# Checkbox fires only at multiple clicks

Tags: c#, winforms

**UPDATE:**
I have improved some things and changed it. 
Now I have to click a second time, the first time the console writes:

```
Der Thread 0x180c hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.(Thread stopped)
```

And on the second checking checkbox it works.

**OLD**
When I click on the checkbox my app should visit URL's. It is working but only if I click multiple times on the checkbox.

So when I want to stop it, it will not work. I have no clue why. It is the same with a button, I have to click it multiple times till it works.

```
private void chVisitProfile_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chVisitProfile.Checked)
    {
        var threadLoading = new ThreadStart(StartVisiting);
        var thread = new Thread(threadLoading);
        thread.Start();
    }
}

private void StartVisiting()
{
    var jsDo = "var urls = '';" +
       "$.each($('.tile__link').find('.info__username'), function(i, b){var profilname = '" + "https://www.website.com/#/profile/" + "' +$(this).text().trim() + '" + "@" + "';urls+=profilname;});" +
       "function returnURL(){thURL = urls;return thURL;} returnURL();";
    var task = chromeControll.EvaluateScriptAsync(jsDo);
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (!t.IsFaulted)
        {
            var response = t.Result;
            var EvaluateJavaScriptResult = response.Success ? (response.Result ?? "null") : response.Message;
            richTextBox1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => richTextBox1.Text = response.Result.ToString()));
        }
    });

    var links = richTextBox1.Text;
    string[] exploded = links.Split('@');

    for (int i = 1; i < exploded.Length; i++)
    {
        if(chVisitProfile.Checked == false)
        {
            break;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        chromeVisit.Load(exploded[i]);
        //lblSeconds.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be unrelated but you should know that `CheckedChanged` will fire even if the `Checked` property is changed programmatically. Is that what you want? You might consider using the `Click` event instead. That said, is this WinForms, WebForms, WPF? Something else? Please use the appropriate tag.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed hey, if the checkbox is checked it should start to visiting. If the checkbox is not checked it should stop.

Comment: Where is the "stop" part in your code?

Comment: I've edited it in "chVisitProfile_CheckedChanged" have a look please.

Comment: Do you realize that each time the `CheckedChanged` event fires, you start a _new_ thread? The one you stop is **Not** the one you started.

Comment: Thats definitly not what I wanted. This makes more clear.

Comment: Got it, I've breaked the for loop and didn't use the Abord now.

Answer (score 1):

Why even start the thread if it is not needed?  I would suggest something like this:

```
private void chVisitProfile_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        var threadLoading = new ThreadStart(StartVisiting);
        var thread = new Thread(threadLoading);
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

This way the thread fires only as needed.  To improve it even more, it can verify if the process is already going (so no need to start a new thread).

Comment: Thanks I changed it.